# Product template search view wrong behavior odoo

Tags: python, searchview, odoo

In product template search view is defined a field to do search by product attributes:

```
<field string="Product Variant" name="product_variant_ids" filter_domain="['|', ('product_variant_ids.name','ilike',self), ('product_variant_ids.attribute_value_ids.name','ilike',self)]"/>
```

product_variants_ids is a one2many field in product.template. When I write some attribute value, it brings the correct record, but if I write the atrribute name, it brings nothing, for example, in attribute page for some product I have:

```
MEMORY      32gb
COLOR       red
```

If I type 32gb, it brings record, whereas if I type MEMORY, brings nothing

Can any one help me? I would like to understand filter_domain

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in the [search view documentation](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/master/reference/views.html#search), they say :

> Possible children elements of the search view are:
>
> ### `field`
>
> fields define domains or contexts with user-provided values. When
>   search domains are generated, field domains are composed with one
>   another and with filters using AND.
>
> Fields can have the following attributes:
>
> ...
>
> - #### `filter_domain`
>
>   complete domain to use as the field’s search domain, can
>     use a `self` variable to inject the provided value in the custom domain.
>     Can be used to generate significantly more flexible domains than
>     `operator` alone (e.g. searches on multiple fields at once)
>
>   If both `operator` and `filter_domain` are provided, `filter_domain` takes
>     precedence.

so for your example, with this as `filter_domain` :

```
[
    '|',
    ('product_variant_ids.name','ilike',self),
    ('product_variant_ids.attribute_value_ids.name','ilike',self)
]
```

if you search `MEMORY`, it will be searched in one of the two given fields (by an ilike which is equivalent to sql's `field ILIKE '%MEMORY%'` for your example).

#### product_variants_ids.name field

the searched value will be 'ilike'd with `product_variants_ids.name`.

`product_variants_ids` [is a one2many](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/d780014248/addons/product/product.py#L574) to a list of `product.product`.

the `name` of a product is the name of his `product.template`.

so this enable us to find `product.template` by name (similar to  `('name', 'ilike', self)` but will find only the `product.template` with a variant).

#### product_variant_ids.attribute_value_ids.name field

`product_variant_ids` is still a list of `product.product`. `attribute_value_ids` [is a many2many](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/d780014248/addons/product/product.py#L964) to `product.attribute.value`.

and the name of this `product.attribute.value` [is the attribute value](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/d780014248/addons/product/product.py#L379), so in your given case `32gb` or `red`.

#### Conclusion

So, this filter will not find `MEMORY` or `COLOR`, these are available in fields :

- [`attribute_line_ids`](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/d780014248/addons/product/product.py#L573).[`attribute_id`](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/d780014248/addons/product/product.py#L414).[`name`](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/d780014248/addons/product/product.py#L334)
- [`product_variant_ids`](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/d780014248/addons/product/product.py#L574).[`attribute_value_ids`](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/d780014248/addons/product/product.py#L964).[`attribute_id`](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/d780014248/addons/product/product.py#L380).[`name`](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/d780014248/addons/product/product.py#L334)

In a product view, you can search on tue attribute names (without change) like this :

- doing an `Advanced Search`,
- Choosing `Product Attributes` `contains` `memory`,
- Clicking on `Apply`.

[image: gui way to do a search on product attribute]